# "system cannot find drive specified" trying to set up new GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

I'm setting up a GitHub repository in Windows so I can host my website there. How would you approach this after typing in command prompt `git clone (url)""`

I've installed `node.js` and `browser-sync`. I've proceeded to follow these videos but for some reason, my computer gives me a prompt of "the system cannot find the drive specified".

https://www.hannatural.com/coursera/

https://hannatural.com/coursera/sublime/

I tried working around that by not typing in `e:` or `d:`

I typed in the following commands:

```
git clone (url)
cd coursera-test (name of the repository)
code . (takes me to visual studio)
```

Setup HTML format and save.

```
git add .
git commit ...
git push
```

If I skip the `e:` or `d:` from the video I get through everything but after typing in git push a prompt appears `"Who is this?"`

Comment: Is this in relation to GitHub or GitUp?

Comment: Github. I apologize for the question if its worded wrong. Im brand new to the Git, Github environment.

Comment: No problem, it was just your title said "Gitup" which is different.

Comment: oh okay just saw that thank you. Theres no way to edit the question correct?

Comment: It's been all fixed for you.

Comment: Please share the complete problem statement. No one is going to look at the videos and see what exactly the issue you are facing.

Comment: You might need to do [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git)

Comment: Sorry im new to stackoverflow but should i delete or answer my own question? I think i got it. Long story short i made a directory and typed in the commands i listed earlier and my html code now appears on the browser. Thank you guys and thank you for the github reference on setting up the email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure to set your user name and email *gobally*

```
git config --global user.name "Your GitHub Account"
git config --global user.email your@email.com
```

That way, it will be valid for *all* local repositories.

Second, if you don't have `d:` and `e:` drive, an error message like "`the system cannot find the drive specified`" is normal and expected: you don't have to switch to those drive and can do everything on `C:\`.

Comment: thank you. I was able to finally resolve the issue.